# How do I get all the days of the week alongside the temperature data displayed from the mapped array from the forecast data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

So basically what I need is for it to display: 7.7 C Monday, 8 C Tuesday, 9 Wednesday, 11 C thursday, etc. I was thinking of using a for loop or maybe a for each method, not entirely sure what to do here as I am new to Javascript, your insight would be very appreciated.

The .forEach() method iterates over an array, and performs a provided task. The 'task' that it will perform is called a callback function. The function tells the .forEach() method which task to perform for each item in the array. Within the callback, we can define two arguments that represent the iterated item, the value and the index.
.forEach() does not return a new array, it simply lets your perform some task on each index within an array.

```
        junohome.weatherdatareq= function (){
            $.ajax({
            url:`${junohome.weatherurl}/current`,
            method:'GET',
            datatype: 'json',
            data: {
                access_key:junohome.weatherkey,
                query:'Toronto'
            }
        }).then(function(datas){
                 autotemp="0";
                if(datas.temperature > 25) 
                {autotemp=22 + '\u00B0 C'}
                else {autotemp=19 + '\u00B0 C'}
                    $(".housetemp").text(autotemp)
                     
                
        
    });

    junohome.forecastdata= function(){
        $.ajax({
           url:`${junohome.forecasturl}/forecast`,
           method: 'GET',
           datatype:'json',
           data: {
            key:junohome.forecastkey,
             days:'5',
             city:'Toronto'
           }
        }).then(function(fdata){
            console.log(fdata)
            
             const forecast = fdata.data.map(function(i){
    return i.temp;
});
const day= fdata.data.map(function(theday){
return function(){
    weekday[day.valid_date]
}
});
let l=new Date();
dayofweek=l.getDay();
getweekday=l.getUTCDay();
weekday=new Array(7);
weekday[0]="Sunday";
weekday[1]="Monday";
weekday[2]="Tuesday";
weekday[3]="Wedensday";
weekday[4]="Thursday";
weekday[5]="Friday";
weekday[6]="Saturday";

console.log(dayofweek)
            $(".forecastblocks").text(forecast + " " + weekday[getweekday])
        });
    }
        }

    const results= junohome.weatherdatareq(); 
    console.log(results);
    const forecast=junohome.forecastdata();
console.log(forecast);

       junohome.clock= 
       function(){
       date=new Date();
      let h=date.getHours();
       let m=date.getMinutes();
       let s=date.getSeconds();
       m=checkTime(m);
       s=checkTime(s);
       let session="Am";
       if(h > 12)
       {session="Pm";}
       else {session="Am"}
       const time= h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " " + session;
       setTimeout(junohome.clock,1000);
       $(".digital-clock").text(time);
       }

junohome.clock();
        

const timing=junohome.clock();
console.log(timing)


function checkTime(time) {
  if (time < 10) {time = "0" + time}; < 10
  return time;
};
        </script>
</body>
```

Comment: JS is perfectly capable of unicode, as is any browser, no need to use `\u00B0`. Also, why are you keeping the temperatures out of the string? Just put them in: ```autotemp = `22° C`;``` (using the same modern templating string syntax. No good reason to mix that with `'` or `"` except when the JS syntax _demands_ it)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, very logical, thank you!